# Can't join any Servers on PC Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Recently I was invited to a Realm, but I've been having issues joining.
Basically, whenever I try to join the Realm, I get to "Downloading Terrain" for a split second, then it instantly switches to "Connection lost: Disconnected".

I've tried joining other servers to Make sure it isn't just the Realm, on the server list it shows the connection strength and everything, but as soon as I join, I get the same thing. What's funny is I was able to personally host a Minecraft server completely fine from my own IP, and I'm able to play online any other game perfectly fine, but Minecraft is the exception here.

I've already Googled all I could think of, trying multiple methods, but so far nothing has worked. I don't really have any other details to give, the launcher acts perfectly normal, not even throwing up an error in the log.

Basically all I'm asking is how can I fix this? I know I didn't give out much details, but hopefully someone can throw out any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any mods? Have you checked your internet connection for dropped/lost packets?

Comment: It sounds like you have a bad internet connection

Comment: I am not using any mods (I actually thought that was an issue, and even went to the extend of redownloading the 1.9 jar) and my internet is fine. Playing/hosting servers on any other game is pretty much lagless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't join any minecraft servers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193209/cant-join-any-minecraft-servers)

Comment: @galacticninja not a dupe. One is instant error, other is timeout.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have something blocking Minecraft from your computer. Do you have something like MeetCircle on? This is the same with mine--single player worlds WILL work, but trying to connect to servers will automatically disconnect you.

Comment: No I don't have anything like that on, unless it's like reeeaaallyy hidden or something. I've already tried disabling what I could, and still no luck, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having that problem also. Maybe your AES key generator is not available. To make it available, it's sort of dizzy doing all that stuff - so It's best if you contact Mojang for support in an e-mail.